# Unable to change icons in the taskbar on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons

I've changed the Firefox icon in taskbar folder and I've restarted and it hasn't changed in the taskbar...

[image]

Comment: Try this with other program. Create a shortcut with the modified icon then pin that shortcut in Taskbar, not the program.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 (8+ really) doesn't use the quicklaunch folder any more. It's simply provided for backwards compatibility with older installers that might fail to complete the installation if they can't add a shortcut to the quicklaunch folder.

Instead, you can edit the icons directly from the taskbar. Simply right-click on the icon in the taskbar and, from the drop down menu that appears, right-click again on `Mozilla Firefox`. From *that* drop down select `Properties` as usual and go from there.